# PowerShell Exception Calling "Unable to cast COM object" - Error loading type library/DLL

Tags: vba, powershell

I have the following script in PowerShell which has been executing fine for months. I did not change anything, but I am receiving the error below. I've tried on other machines, but I keep receiving the same error. Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I would have to get our IT involved for any registry or permission changes, and I would have to walk them through the process as well.

**Script**

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ms_access = New-Object -comobject Access.Application

function Test-IsFileAvailable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Leaf)) {
        # the file is not found
        Write-Verbose "File '$Path' not found."
        return $false
    }

    try {
        $file   = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path
        $stream = $file.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                             [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                             [System.IO.FileShare]::None)

        if ($stream) { $stream.Close() }
        Write-Verbose "File '$Path' is not locked."
        return $true
    } 
    catch {
        # file is locked by a process.
        Write-Verbose "File '$Path' is locked by another process."
        return $false
    }
}

#set path files
$FilePath_raw = 'N:\DATA\StatusReport_Raw.xlsx'

$FilePath_report = 'N:DATA\StatusReport.xlsx'

$FilePath_date = 'N:\DATA\ReportDate.xlsx'

$FilePath_access = "N:\DATA\Access\Processing.accdb"

if (!(Test-IsFileAvailable $FilePath_raw -Verbose)) { exit }
if (!(Test-IsFileAvailable $FilePath_report -Verbose)) { exit }
if (!(Test-IsFileAvailable $FilePath_date -Verbose)) { exit }
if (!(Test-IsFileAvailable $FilePath_access -Verbose)) { exit }


#make it visible ($true) or invisible ($false)
$excel.Visible = $false

$wb_eval1 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath_raw)
$ws_eval1 = $wb_eval1.sheets.Item(1)

$wb_eval2 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath_report)
$ws_eval2 = $wb_eval2.sheets.Item(1)

$wb_date = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath_date)
$ws_date = $wb_date.sheets.Item(1)

$ws_eval2.Cells.Clear()
$lrow2 = $ws_eval1.usedRange.Rows.Count
$range2=$ws_eval1.Range("A3:AA$lrow2")
$range2.copy()
$cpy_range_eval = $ws_eval2.Range("A1")
$ws_eval2.Paste($cpy_range_eval)

$date_range = $ws_eval1.Range("B1")
$date_range.copy()

$cpy_range_date = $ws_date.Range("A2")
$ws_date.Paste($cpy_range_date)

$wb_date.Save()
$wb_date.Close()

$wb_eval2.Save()
$wb_eval2.Close()
$wb_eval1.Close()

$ms_access.OpenCurrentDatabase($Filepath_access)
$ms_access.Run("ExportExcel")

$excel.Quit() 
$ms_access.Quit()

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb_eval1)  | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb_eval2)  | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb_date)   | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)     | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ms_access) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$excel = $ms_access = $null

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$output = $wshell.Popup("The task has finished")


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$global:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
$balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info 
$balloon.BalloonTipText = 'The reports have been processed.'
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = "Attention $Env:USERNAME" 
$balloon.Visible = $true 
$balloon.ShowBalloonTip(20000)
```

**Error Message**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your
shell will retain its current effective execution policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help
Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:46
+ ...  -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'N ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
VERBOSE: File 'N:\DATA\StatusReport_Raw.xlsx' is not locked.
VERBOSE: File 'N:\DATA\StatusReport.xlsx' is not locked.
VERBOSE: File 'N:\DATA\ReportDate.xlsx' is not locked.
VERBOSE: File 'N:\DATA\Access\Processing.accdb' is not locked.
True
True
True
Exception calling "OpenCurrentDatabase" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast COM object of type
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access._Application'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
'{68CCE6C0-6129-101B-AF4E-00AA003F0F07}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."
At N:\RUN\RUN.ps1:82 char:1
+ $ms_access.OpenCurrentDatabase($Filepath_access)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastException

Exception calling "Run" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast COM object of type
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access._Application'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
'{68CCE6C0-6129-101B-AF4E-00AA003F0F07}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."
At N:\RUN\RUN.ps1:83 char:1
+ $ms_access.Run("ExportExcel")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastException

Exception calling "Quit" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to cast COM object of type
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access._Application'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
'{68CCE6C0-6129-101B-AF4E-00AA003F0F07}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."
At N:\RUN\RUN.ps1:86 char:1
+ $ms_access.Quit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastException
```

Comment: Maybe a 32 bits Powershell trying to run a 64 bits Access, or vice versa?

Comment: I do have 32-bit MS Access. I just tried running the script on  Windows PowerShell ISE (x86) and I received the same error. Is there anything else I should test in regards to a 32-bit and 64-bit mismatch?

Comment: Looks like your central IT department has added some rules to Grouo Policy to configure PowerShell Execution Policy. From the error message, they’ve set it to Remote Signed. In my experience that’s normally enough to run most scripts - are you sure you need “Bypass”, or could you just use Remote Signed?

Comment: I believe Remote Signed works just fine. I have run into this before. I normally hit "Accept All" and it works. Should I do anything with the policy then?

Answer (score 2):

So if I am understanding the problem the solution should be quite simple.  Before you run the Powershell script right click on it and hit run as administrator.  The reason the error is occurring is that you need escalated privileges to set the execution policy. As for the other issue it may be that those files are now protected and therefore unable to load so by using the run as administration option it should allow it to access those files.

I have had several issue in the past where just running with escalated permissions has fixed problems.  Now I would not do this as a permanent fix but if this works it would at least get it working again.[This is why you shouldn't](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2004/06/17/why-you-shouldnt-run-as-admin/)

Comment: I don't have the option to run as an administrator by right clicking. I thought that was the case before, but it was working just fine. It just broke all of a sudden with no changes on my end. Can I run it elevated another way? I will have to get IT to do it with their admin privileges then.

Comment: I would say see if you can get them to run it and see if that works.  That would at least tell you if there was an issue related to permissions.  It could have been they pushed some policy changes to the device.  If that is the issue then you might want to see if they can give you a service account or something to run with elevated permissions.

Comment: I put in the ticket with my IT and I am waiting to hear back. I did not forget, and I appreciate your assistance. I will post back once I get them to try to run it elevated. I actually converted the entire process over to Python since I want to learn Python anyway, so it was a good learning experience.

Comment: The IT guy couldn't figure anything out. I tried a few things and used his admin permissions, but nothing was working. The Python script is running great though, and it's better than the original script I created. I will try to elevate it to Tier 2 support and see. I appreciate your advice!